# c++: using memcpy when source/destination has "std::string" value

Tags: c++, memcpy, stdstring

I have following question - when I'm trying to use memcopy function to copy content of struct to other struct i observed that, function does not work correctly for std::string data.

I created a piece of code to analyze this case:

```
struct Test1
{

    int Value;
    std::string Text;

};

Test1 Values;

Values.Text = "Failflood";
Values.Value = 1;

Test1 ValuesOut;

std::cout << "SizeofInt: std::string: " << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;
std::cout << "SizeofInt: int: " << sizeof(int) << std::endl;

std::cout << "ValuesOutAddress: " << &ValuesOut << std::endl;
std::cout << "ValuesAddress: " << &Values << std::endl;
std::cout << "ValuesOutSize: " << sizeof(&ValuesOut) << std::endl;
std::cout << "ValuesSize: " << sizeof(&Values) << std::endl;
std::cout << "TestSize: " << sizeof(Test1) << std::endl;

memcpy(&ValuesOut, &Values, sizeof(&ValuesOut));

std::cout << "Values.Text: " << Values.Text << std::endl;
std::cout << "ValuesOut.Text: " << ValuesOut.Text << std::endl;

std::cout << "Values.Value: " << Values.Value << std::endl;
std::cout << "ValuesOut.Value: " << ValuesOut.Value << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
SizeofInt: std::string: 40
SizeofInt: int: 4
ValuesOutAddress: 000000BB63AFFAF8
ValuesAddress: 000000BB63AFFAA8
ValuesOutSize: 8
ValuesSize: 8
TestSize: 48
Values.Text: Failflood
ValuesOut.Text:
Values.Value: 1
ValuesOut.Value: 1
```

My conclusion is that, there is an issue with size of struct, but i don't understand (1) why there is such behaviour observed (std::string is not copied, Values and ValuesOut has size 8, but struct has size 48...), (2) I wonder if i can handle this problem somehow or i need to use char[X] instead or change approach and not use memcpy. I want to use memcpy, because in my project i have a structure with a lot of fields to copy and i find memcpy handy in this case. Could anyone clarify my problem ?

Comment: The search term for further research is [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable). `std::string` is not, and so any struct or class containing it as a member isn't either.

Comment: Why memcpy? `ValuesOut = Values;` works perfectly.

Comment: `sizeof(&ValuesOut)` is not the size of the variable `ValuesOut`, but of the pointer pointing to it. Compare and contrast with `sizeof(ValuesOut)` (note no ampersand)

Comment: You simply can't use `memcpy` to copy a `std::string`.  Trying will only bring you pain in the form of undefined behavior.

Comment: Now it's clear to me, thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't copying the whole structure. This line:

```
memcpy(&ValuesOut, &Values, sizeof(&ValuesOut));
```

only copies `sizeof(&ValuesOut)` bytes, and that's the size of a pointer, whatever `ValuesOut` is. So the `memcpy` call only copies the `Value` member of your struct (and probably some padding bytes, if `sizeof(int)` is less than the size of a pointer). The result is that `ValuesOut.Text` stays empty (default-constructed).

You probably meant to write `sizeof(ValuesOut)` instead. However, if you do that, you will run into undefined behavior, because `std::string` holds a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, and you will only copy that pointer, not the memory. In reality, it's even more complicated because of short string optimization.

In short: `std::string` is a complex type, and you should never `memcpy` it. Simply use its copy or move constructors.